# Sonar-Eclipse Integration

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I am integrating sonar version-3.2 with eclipse juno(version-4.2). i have installed this plugin through eclipse "install new software".... Now after integration when i add sonar server in eclipse by going to eclipse preferences window it ask for sonar server URL, username and password,i provide these details (assuming username and password of sonar) and click on test connection then it through "unable to connect" message.

do anyone know what would be the reason behind this??

what is the significance of username and password here??

Kindly revert in case anybody have any idea over it..

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have [Sonar 3.4 or higher](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar+in+Eclipse) on your server to access it from Eclipse Juno. Older versions can only be accessed from Helios and Indigo.